# get the id and description from database for dropdown in django

Tags: django, django-models, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to create a dropdown in my django form. I am new to django framework. In ASP.NET MVC, we use LINQ or SQL Procedure to fetch data and also in model class we can do,

```
/// model class

[NotMapped]
public string ddl_productdesc
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format("{1} --- {2}", ProductID, I_NUMBER, ProductDESC);
    }
}
```

In my table, there are around 30 columns from them I need three fields (`ProductID`, `I_NUMBER`, `ProductDESC`) for my dropdown

How can I do the same in django, the `ID` field used for data fetching and insertion and other two fields as dropdown? Thank You!

Comment: Have you tried writing any code that you want help with or are you looking for a general answer?

Comment: I don't have any idea how to do this in Django. I am from .NET backgroThis is my first project in Django. Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the answer to my comment, you are a complete django beginner. Therefore, I recommend starting with the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/).

I will provide you with some guidance nevertheless. First, you write yourself a view similar to this (note that this is very minimalistic):

```py
def product_view(request):
    context = { 'products': Products.objects.all() }
    return render(request, 'products/product_view.html', context)
```

Then, in that `product_view.html` template, you can create dropdowns like this:

```py
{% if products %}
  <label for="products">Choose a product:</label>

  <select name="cars" id="cars">
  {% for product in products %}
    <option value="{{ product.pk }}">{{ product.name }} -- {{ product.number}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
  </select>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Why shall we retrieve all the columns from database? How can I retrieve only the required columns `(ProductID, I_NUMBER, ProductDESC)` from the table? Is it possible? Thank You!

Comment: Yes, that's possible with values(). Just scroll through the docs, all your questions will be answered: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#values